# I heard that INC instruction is not atomic. Then, how CAS instruction can be atomic?

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic, lock-free, compare-and-swap

CAS is very primitive lock free technique, and I know that it is atomic.

Also, it is much more complex operation than INC.

It should compare value and if value is not changed, CAS sets the new value while guaranteeing that other thread does not access it.

Then, how can CAS is atomic while INC is not.

I also learned that LOCK INC is atomic operation, but with expensive cost than INC.

If CAS also uses some similar technique like LOCK INC internally, then why is it called lock free technique?

Is lock used in CAS is different from normal lock we usually know?

If so, how much different between cost of normal lock and cas?

Comment: Why tag this as `C`?

Comment: If you're talking about x86 (which `inc/lock inc` suggests), then `cmpxchg` is not atomic either. `lock cmpxchg` is atomic.

Answer (score 1):

CaS is different from locked inc. LOCK INC semantically locks the memory and performs increment (lock does not always happen, but the effect is as is it was). As a result, LOCK INC is guranteed to increment the value, and if two LOCK INC are issued at the same time from two different threads on the same value, the result would be value incremented exactly twice. LOCK INC can never fail.

CaS is 'try and see' operation. The operation is attempted (namely, set value to X if it is Y) and it can either succeed - if value is indeed Y or fail, if it is something else. There is no guanratee that it will succeed. If two threads are issuing the same CaS operation on the same value at the same time, only one of them will succeed, while the other will fail.

There is also a concept of 'atomic increment', which basically means 'increment value, but do not lock it'. The way it is usually done is by trying to do CaS in a loop to the new incremented value until it succeeds. Every fail means the new value and the check value will be adjusted. As a result, atomic increment can potentially be slow on a high-contented values.

Answer (score 0):

Compare and swap (CAS) is implemented as an atomic processor operation on most processor architectures.  Since it is atomic at the hardware level, no explicit lock is needed when using it.  C compilers generally know if the target architecture has the instruction, so if you use the compare and swap operation in the atomic library, it will most likely use this hardware operation if available, without incurring the overhead of an explicit lock.

"Increment" is not well defined in a multithreaded environment; if another thread has changed the value since the current thread read it, should the result of the increment operation be one more than the value the current thread read, or one more than the value the other thread wrote?  For most people the intuitive result is that it should be one more than the value the current thread read, but only if another thread hasn't written to it, which actually makes increment a more complex operation than a compare and swap.